# TestFlight: when i upload a new version of the app, my latest code changes are not showing

Tags: ios, testflight

I have been uploading versions of my app to TestFlight for the last few months without any issue.

Today i tried to upload a new build to TestFlight. As always i changed the version number (1.5 -> 1.6).

I can see version 1.6 in TestFlight.

Within the TestFlight app i see version 1.6 available to download.

All good so far.

The issue is that when i download 1.6 i don't see any of the changes that have been made since 1.5. The app code is still effectively 1.5..

If i go into Xcode and build the app, i do see the changes that i made for 1.6.

But it is as if it is archiving 1.5.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you've uploaded the correct IPA? It seems impossible.

Comment: I think i am. In Xcode i am going to Product -> Archive, and then selecting the latest in the list of archives.

Comment: I think you should add a version for example 1.0.0 and each time you want to update that you should increase just the build number, in the organizer you can see it, the version and the build number for example 1.0.0(1), 1.0.0(2), 1.0.0(3), ...(it's not a solution but it's a more simple way for the testflight without changing each time the profile of the app)